# wxGridBagSizer: only shows half of the bottom row

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm attempting to use a `wxGridBagLayout` to lay out a bunch of toggle buttons in a particular shape. It works for the most part, however, the bottom row (row 5, containing `btnA`) is partially obscured at the minimum size. How do I work around, or otherwise fix this?

Below is the layout class involved.

```cpp
  class ButtonsPanel : public wxStaticBox {
  public:
    ButtonsPanel(wxWindow* parent);
    
    // this isn't relevant
    BUTTONS QueryState();

  private:
    wxToggleButton* btnL;
    wxToggleButton* btnZ;
    wxToggleButton* btnR;

    wxStaticText* lblD;
    wxToggleButton* btnDU;
    wxToggleButton* btnDD;
    wxToggleButton* btnDL;
    wxToggleButton* btnDR;

    wxToggleButton* btnStart;
    wxToggleButton* btnB;
    wxToggleButton* btnA;

    wxStaticText* lblC;
    wxToggleButton* btnCU;
    wxToggleButton* btnCD;
    wxToggleButton* btnCL;
    wxToggleButton* btnCR;
  };
```

```cpp
  ButtonsPanel::ButtonsPanel(wxWindow* parent) :
    wxStaticBox(parent, wxID_ANY, "Buttons"),
    btnL(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "L", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnZ(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Z", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnR(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "R", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),

    lblD(new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "D")),
    btnDU(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "^", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnDD(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "v", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnDL(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "<", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnDR(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, ">", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),

    btnStart(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "S", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnB(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "B", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnA(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "A", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),

    lblC(new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "C")),
    btnCU(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "^", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnCD(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "v", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnCL(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, "<", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)),
    btnCR(new wxToggleButton(this, wxID_ANY, ">", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBU_EXACTFIT)) {
      
    for (auto* i : {btnDU, btnDD, btnDL, btnDR, btnCU, btnCD, btnCL, btnCR, btnStart, btnB, btnA}) {
      auto currSize = i->GetSize();
      i->SetMinSize({currSize.GetHeight(), currSize.GetHeight()});
    }
    
    auto* gridSizer = new wxGridBagSizer(2, 2);
    // gridSizer->SetFlexibleDirection(wxVERTICAL);
    // gridSizer->SetNonFlexibleGrowMode(wxFLEX_GROWMODE_ALL);
    
    gridSizer->Add(btnL, {0, 0}, {1, 3}, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnZ, {0, 3}, {1, 3}, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnR, {0, 6}, {1, 3}, wxEXPAND);
    
    gridSizer->Add(lblD, {2, 1}, wxDefaultSpan, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnDU, {1, 1}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnDD, {3, 1}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnDL, {2, 0}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnDR, {2, 2}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    
    gridSizer->Add(btnStart, {2, 4});
    gridSizer->Add(btnB, {4, 5}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnA, {5, 6}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, ""), {4, 6}, wxDefaultSpan, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxEXPAND);
    
    gridSizer->Add(lblC, {2, 7}, wxDefaultSpan, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnCU, {1, 7}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnCD, {3, 7}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnCL, {2, 6}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    gridSizer->Add(btnCR, {2, 8}, wxDefaultSpan, wxEXPAND);
    
    for (auto* i : {btnDU, btnDD, btnDL, btnDR, btnCU, btnCD, btnCL, btnCR, btnStart, btnB, btnA}) {
      gridSizer->SetItemMinSize(i, i->GetMinSize());
    }
    
    auto* hSizer = new wxGridSizer(1, 1, 3, 3);
    hSizer->Add(gridSizer, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 3);
    
    SetSizerAndFit(hSizer);
  }
```

Comment: where did you call `Layout()`?

Comment: I didn't know you had to call Layout(). Anyway, the issue was solved by using wxStaticBoxSizer and a wxPanel.